# How to add a button to quill toolbar

Tags: javascript, quill

I cannot figure out how to add a button to toolbar like '@'
I tried using an extension to make it, but the console always shows some warning. Here's my code -

```
    import at from 'src/assets/icons/at-sign.svg'
    import Quill from 'quill'
    import Icons from 'quill/ui/icons'
    import At from './at'
    Icons.at = at
    Quill.register(
      'ui/icons', Icons
    )
    Quill.register(
      'formats/at', At
    )
    export default Quill
```

Then I use the quill after re-registering, like this -

```
    var toolbarOptions = [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link', 'at']        // toggled buttons
      ]
      this.editor = new Quill('#editorContainer', {
        modules: {
          toolbar: toolbarOptions
        },
        placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
        theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
      })
    }
```

Then console warning says 'toolbar ignoring attaching to nonexistent format at '

Where am I going wrong, please help!

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with the code in './at'. Can you post that code to see if the format was created correctly?